# Bean of type String that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

This webapp is going to work with database, but for now I've started with an easiest stub and got stuck.

I'm kinda clueless what is wrong. Overall I'm not that familiar with Spring or with how to understand and trace such errors. The only thing I understand here is that it has nothing to do with the type of a method argument. I've googled this error, looked into some answers about this kind of error here, but failed at finding the right solution.

So, I'm getting this:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-05-22 15:44:36.132  INFO 17992 --- [           main] c.rinkashikachi.SpringReactApplication   : Starting SpringReactApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on DESKTOP-3BPPMPQ with PID 17992 (D:\Projects\J
ava\zni\target\zni-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by 15rin in D:\Projects\Java\zni)
2020-05-22 15:44:36.135  INFO 17992 --- [           main] c.rinkashikachi.SpringReactApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-22 15:44:37.108  INFO 17992 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-05-22 15:44:37.116  INFO 17992 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-22 15:44:37.116  INFO 17992 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-05-22 15:44:37.166  INFO 17992 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-22 15:44:37.166  INFO 17992 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 999 ms
2020-05-22 15:44:37.241  WARN 17992 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springfram
ework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'utilController' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Projects/Java/zni/target/zni-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/co
m/rinkashikachi/controllers/UtilController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyExcep
tion: Error creating bean with name 'databaseMetaDataService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'getTableListBySchema' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.fact
ory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2020-05-22 15:44:37.244  INFO 17992 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-05-22 15:44:37.252  INFO 17992 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-05-22 15:44:37.326 ERROR 17992 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method getTableListBySchema in com.rinkashikachi.service.DatabaseMetaDataService required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
```

This is where the method is.

```
package com.rinkashikachi.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.rinkashikachi.service.repositories.ColNameEntity;
import com.rinkashikachi.service.repositories.TableNameEntity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service("databaseMetaDataService")
public class DatabaseMetaDataService {

    @Autowired
    public List<TableNameEntity> getTableListBySchema(String schema) {

        // Stub
        List<TableNameEntity> names = new ArrayList<>(3);
        switch(schema) {
            case "ADDITIONAL":
                names.add(new TableNameEntity(1L, "ADDITIONAL1"));
                names.add(new TableNameEntity(2L, "ADDITIONAL2"));
                names.add(new TableNameEntity(3L, "ADDITIONAL3"));
                break;
            case "BOOKKEEPING":
                names.add(new TableNameEntity(1L, "BOOKKEEPING1"));
                names.add(new TableNameEntity(2L, "BOOKKEEPING2"));
                names.add(new TableNameEntity(3L, "BOOKKEEPING3"));
                break;
        }
        return names;
    }
}
```

And this is where I use it:

```
package com.rinkashikachi.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.rinkashikachi.service.DatabaseMetaDataService;
import com.rinkashikachi.service.repositories.TableNameEntity;


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class UtilController {

    private final DatabaseMetaDataService databaseMetaDataService;

    @Autowired
    public UtilController(DatabaseMetaDataService databaseMetaDataService) {
        this.databaseMetaDataService = databaseMetaDataService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/tech")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getTechData(
            @RequestParam(value="schema") String schema,
            @RequestParam(value="table", required = false) String table,
            @RequestParam(value="column", required = false) String column) {
        List<TableNameEntity> entityList = databaseMetaDataService.getTableListBySchema(schema);
        List<String> tables = new ArrayList<>(entityList.size());

        for (TableNameEntity entity : entityList) {
            tables.add(entity.toString());
            System.out.println(entity);
        }

        return !tables.isEmpty()
                ? new ResponseEntity<>(tables, HttpStatus.OK)
                : new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to autowire a `String schema` into your method `getTableListBySchema`. Obviously you have no `String` typed bean in your application context.

Comment: You don't need the ```@Autowired``` annotation in ```getTableListBySchema(String schema)``` method. You don't have a ```@Bean``` of type string in your configuration to inject.

Comment: thanks, I'm dumb. Guess I'm too tired to think and need to have a rest

Comment: @Rinkashikachi take a good rest,all problems will disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking the `getTableListBySchema` method as `Autowired` tells spring to do the dependency injection here. That is why Spring looks for a bean of type `Spring` to autowire it to the method argument. Remove the `Autowired` annotation from that method.

As a side-note, if you are developing an api. You should be using the `@RestController` not `@Controller`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this code:

@Autowired
public List getTableListBySchema(**String schema**) {

Can you try:

```
package com.rinkashikachi.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.rinkashikachi.service.repositories.ColNameEntity;
import com.rinkashikachi.service.repositories.TableNameEntity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service("databaseMetaDataService")
public class DatabaseMetaDataService {


    public List<TableNameEntity> getTableListBySchema(String schema) {

        // Stub
        List<TableNameEntity> names = new ArrayList<>(3);
        switch(schema) {
            case "ADDITIONAL":
                names.add(new TableNameEntity(1L, "ADDITIONAL1"));
                names.add(new TableNameEntity(2L, "ADDITIONAL2"));
                names.add(new TableNameEntity(3L, "ADDITIONAL3"));
                break;
            case "BOOKKEEPING":
                names.add(new TableNameEntity(1L, "BOOKKEEPING1"));
                names.add(new TableNameEntity(2L, "BOOKKEEPING2"));
                names.add(new TableNameEntity(3L, "BOOKKEEPING3"));
                break;
        }
        return names;
    }
}
```

```
package com.rinkashikachi.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.rinkashikachi.service.DatabaseMetaDataService;
import com.rinkashikachi.service.repositories.TableNameEntity;


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class UtilController {
    @Autowired
    private DatabaseMetaDataService databaseMetaDataService;


    @GetMapping(value="/tech")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getTechData(
            @RequestParam(value="schema") String schema,
            @RequestParam(value="table", required = false) String table,
            @RequestParam(value="column", required = false) String column) {
        List<TableNameEntity> entityList = databaseMetaDataService.getTableListBySchema(schema);
        List<String> tables = new ArrayList<>(entityList.size());

        for (TableNameEntity entity : entityList) {
            tables.add(entity.toString());
            System.out.println(entity);
        }

        return !tables.isEmpty()
                ? new ResponseEntity<>(tables, HttpStatus.OK)
                : new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```